# Is there any func or alg in opengl about 2byte unsigned short image to float?

Tags: image, opengl

I have problem with image convert.
I have 16bit unsigned short image and I read this 2byte unsigned short array.
and I want to convert to float array.
Is there any function or algorithm in opengl about this ?

I have my own function but It is not correct. It's coercion.

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose of [transferring pixel data](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer) to textures, OpenGL has internal mechanisms to convert between various pixel formats. But those are *internal* mechanisms; they write directly to OpenGL textures.

There are mechanisms to read as well, but again, they read from OpenGL textures or other images. So there's no way to do a "my memory to my memory" conversion. Well, I suppose you could by uploading to a texture with `glTexImage2D`, then downloading it again with `glGetTexImage`. But that would be pretty terrible, performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any function or algorithm in opengl about this ?

OpenGL is a API designed for drawing things. It's not an all purpose imaging and graphics data manipulation library. Technically it is possible to (ab-)use OpenGL for this, but it's just wrong.

Also, converting between number formats is not terribly difficult, though it takes a few precautions to get it right: http://kaba.hilvi.org/programming/range/index.htm